# Get account name or email when using Google Drive Rest API in C# app

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-account

I'm new to C# and I'm creating a WPF C# app. I want use Google Drive Rest API to send backup file to Google Drive. But this isn't problem. When I wrote Android app in Java, getting account name was very easy. But in C# and my desktop app, I don't now how do this. I read many topic and Google documentation, but I didn't find answer.
Here is my code for Helper class. I only want to get the account name or address and display it in the main window.

I found a solution with Google+ API, but now it doesn't work because Google+ doesn't exist.

Is there any way to do this?

```
    UserCredential credential;

    public DriveService GetGoogleDriveService()
    {
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/menadzer_zespolow_token.json");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            

            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            return service;
        }
        
    }

    public String GetAccountEmail()
    {
        // code to get account name or email there
        return accountNameOrEmail;
    }
```

Comment: Might need to provide more code.  Just looking at this I do not see where accountNameOrEmail is being set.

Comment: I want use GetAccountEmail method to initialize string variable in ViewModel class. This variable is binding with textblock Text parametr. So nothing complicated, before I expand the project, I want to bring these little things to the state I want. :)

Comment: The Drive API does not have a method to get the user's email, but you should be able to get it from their credentials. Can you clarify how the user interacts with your app?

Comment: I have button in MainWindow do Log In to Google Drive. When user click on his, I use GetGoogleDriveService to create Drive Service. I have my "credentials.json" file from Google Console, and use them to get token.json. And that is all. Now if user logged in succesfull i change button content on for example "Logged in", but I want something like "Logged in as". This isn't muuch important, but it's look nice. :) Do you have any example how get any information from credentials?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including links to the libraries you are using, etc. So that we can try and help you better.